# Applying $filter option to GetRecentFiles call in MS Graph API

Tags: odata, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using [getRecentFiles](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_recent) MS Graph API and I'd like to filter out only certain file types (by file extension). However, when I try $filter query parameter it is ignored. Documentation on the method doesn't mention anything like this.

Is this behavior expected or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is expected as no OData query parameters link is not present on the page (when OData query parameters are supported, then its listed in a paragraph).

I have not managed to make it work, neither for drive item properties (eg. id, creation date) nor for nested properties (remoteItem/name or remoteItem/createdBy/user).